# NginX - From Non-SSL Domain to New SSL Domain - Proper redirect needed

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx, https

Here's the situation:

1. Old domain (none-SSL) let's call it "no-ssldomain.com"
2. New domain (with-SSL) let's call it "ssldomain.com"

Both domain points to the same SERVER. So using both domains work.

No-ssldomain.com has been running for 7 years, but since my sought after domain name is now available, i registered it with SSL and trying to move to it for good.

It is running on Wordpress, and all permalinks work, all redirects work. Old no-ssldomain.com nested links redirect perfectly to new ssldomain.com. So no google penalties. Nice.

What my current config does (used semicolon because I cannot post more than 2 links):

1. if you enter: **http;//no-ssldomain.com** > *redirects to* > **https;//ssldomain.com**
2. if you enter: **https;//no-ssldomain.com** > *redirects to* > **https;//ssldomain.com**
3. if you enter: **http;//no-ssldomain.com/xx/xx/xx** > *redirects to* > **https;//ssldomain.com/xx/xx/xx**

But found 1 annoying problem.

if you enter: **https;//no-ssldomain.com/xx/** it opens the webpage using the **no-ssldomain.com** and has an insecure warning. It doesn't redirect to the new **ssldomain.com**. So how can I redirect it properly?

Here's my server config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name no-ssldomain.com;
        location / {
                rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" http://$host/$3 permanent;
        }
        if ($host = "no-ssldomain.com") {
                return 301 https://ssldomain.com$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /xxx/xxx/ssldomain_com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /xxx/xxx/server.key;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name ssldomain.com;
        location /wp-admin {
                index index.php;
        }
        location / {
                index index.php;
                rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" https://ssldomain.com/$3 permanent;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after an hour of trying.

What I did is install a free certificate from Let's Encrypt for the no-ssldomain.com, and now I can listen to port 443 for the said domain.

Then change the first "server" section of my config to:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem;

        server_name no-ssldomain.com www.no-ssldomain.com;

        return 301 https://ssldomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

And then everything worked as expected! Thanks!